# Terminal error in opening program

Tags: macos, terminal

I am on OS X 10.8.5 and when and I am trying to open a program Multiwfn via terminal and receive this error:

```
s229-153:~ brianlevandowski$ /Users/brianlevandowski/Desktop/Multiwfn ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/OpenMotif-2.1.32-22i/lib/libXm.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brianlevandowski/Desktop/Multiwfn
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Read the message carefully, especially the bit starting 'Library not loaded' and ending 'Image not found'. Now, what's your question?

Comment: My question would be what is the easiest way to troubleshoot this? I'm not familiar with What library not loaded/image not found terms

Comment: To load '/usr/OpenMotif-2.1.32-22i/lib/libXm.3.dylib', the file 'libXm.3.dylib' needs to exist, right? In the Finder, if you "Go to folder" and look at the contents of '/usr/OpenMotif-2.1.32-22i/lib/', is there any 'libXm.3.dylib' there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install (or reinstall) OpenMotif. Their website appears to be here: http://www.opengroup.org/openmotif

Edit:
I get the feeling, even if you get Multiwfn running, it won't be stable. It relies on OpenMotif, whose website implies they gave up development in the OS X 10.4 era. Also the author writes "I cannot guarantee that Linux and Mac OS X versions [of Multiwfn] are as robust as Windows version, since all of my developments and most debugging are performed in Windows environment" I think you are trying to install abandon-ware :(

Comment: Here are my instructions:Mac OS X version of Multiwfn works well on Mac OS X 10.8, for other versions I am not sure if Multiwfn can work normally. The installation process is:
1 Uncompress the program package to for example /Users/sob/Multiwfn. Notice that the path (including file name) should less than 80 characters.
￼

Comment: 2 Download .dmg file of Mac OS X version of openmotif from http://www.ist- inc.com/downloads/motif_download.html and then install it. If your system does not natively support X11 (i.e. OS X Mountain Lion), you should download XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing and install it.
3 Add below two sentenses to your .profile file (e.g. /Users/sob/.profile) to make them take effect automatically, then reboot your terminal. If the .profile is unexisting, you should create it manually.

Comment: 3 Add below two sentenses to your .profile file (e.g. /Users/sob/.profile) to make them take effect automatically, then reboot your terminal. If the .profile is unexisting, you should create it manually.
export KMP_STACKSIZE=64000000
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/sob/Multiwfn
KMP_STACKSIZE defines stacksize (in bytes) for each thread in parallel implementation, see Section 2.4 for detail.

Comment: 4 Run sysctl -a|grep shmmax to check if the size of SysV shared memory segments is large enough (unit is in bytes), if the value is too small, Multiwfn may crashes when analyzing big wavefunction. In order to enlarge the size, you should edit or create the file /etc/sysctl.conf, and add kern.sysv.shmmax = 512000000 to it and reboot system, then the upper limit will be enlarged to about 512MB.

Comment: I am stuck on 3 I am not sure what the .profile file is. The path to my Multiwfn application I am trying to open is /Users/brianlevandowski/Desktop/Multiwfn

Comment: Files beginning with a period, like '.profile' are hidden. From the Open dialog in Mac applications, you can see hidden files by pressing the command+shift+period keys at the same time. If you need to create the .profile file, see Nicole's answer on  http://superuser.com/questions/313275/where-to-create-a-profile-on-mac-os-x. Having said that, I have little idea if the steps you wrote are all necessary. I simply see that the error you quoted indicates a missing file, and the file is provided by the OpenMotif software.

Comment: Okay it now says      dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libdislin_d.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Multiwfn
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout  In trying to fix this I searched for libdislin_d.10.dylib in the finder at it exists already. Im not exactly sure where to move it to.

Comment: The message says the parent directory is /usr/local/lib/. I would not *move* it though, I would either copy it, or soft link it (using "ln -s [source] [destination]")

Comment: Ugh... I don't even have this "Dislin" library on my system, must not be  part of OS X by default. Does Multiwfn list its system requirements anywhere? If the people who created Multiwfn bothered to distribute it to the public, I would think they would also list any dependencies it requires.

Comment: Okay so this installer looks likely to include libdislin_d: http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/darwin.html